# How feasible is the idea of preventing alien destruction of humanity through redoubt?

Tags: aliens

I believe that humanity is not going to win every war against aliens in the future since there may be aliens that are way more advanced than us. One way to prevent human annihilation is to send some people far away from human civilization and let them start a new civilization somewhere so that if the main human civilization is gone humanity still exist.

How feasible is this idea, may I ask?

Comment: I seriously doubt the aliens are willing to go so far as to kick us out of the competition, that's assuming we are not the only game in town.

Comment: We're on the worldbuilding site. So we are talking about a fictional setting here, right? What makes the better story?

Comment: @o.m. yes you are right what makes a better story is that the alien came from seemingly across the galaxy to offer spring cleaning service and then missed a spot, we are saved! lol.

Comment: Hi Ying Zhou, welcome to Worldbuilding SE. As o.m. writes it, we are on worldbuilding, so you should consider developing a bit your question. Are some current leaders aware/afraid of a possible alien-based extermination and plan for a survival route? Are we set in the future and a menace from an alien civilization, a real thing? Etc. You can edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A redoubt (aka not putting all our eggs into one basket) might be a good idea even if it does not assume hostile aliens. Humanity on Earth is vulnerable to another dinosaur-killer impact, a lethal epidemic, runaway nanotech, and countless other scenarios. For most of those going to Mars would be enough, but who knows? So if the technology is available, why not go to another system?

- A redoubt strategy against *natural* disasters doesn't have to hide the location of the redoubt. A scientific or industrial colony could be augmented by genetic and cultural information to preserve mankind if homeworld falls silent.
- Then there is the option that part of humanity builds a redoubt against hostilities by *other parts* of humanity. That would fit all the requirements of a human redoubt, except for the selection of culture which is preserved.
- Even if we tried, could we hide the redoubt? Interstellar travel requires lots of energy, and that tends to have a visible signature.

Comment: In respect of the second point, there is always the risk that the off-world colonies become that hostile party, once they've become established and develop a degree of independence from Earth. After long enough, they may cease to consider themselves as earthling humans, especially if the new environment(s) causes or requires physiological changes.

Answer (score 2):

This idea has been explored before.  One example is [David Weber's Safehold series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safehold), which is based around a society established on another world as a refuge against aliens which have destroyed the remainder of humanity.

The feasibility depends on the presence or absence of a useful FTL drive.  Without one, humanity would have to have already started sending out sleeper or generation ships, with one, it may be possible to send out a secret mission to start a new colony under the alien's noses (Figuratively, of course, they may not even *have* noses).

**Edit**

If an alien species advanced enough to travel between the stars arrives and decides to wipe us out, it is unlikely that we'll be able to escape anywhere in our own solar system, and it is also a little unlikely that simply having skipped off to the next remotely habitable planet will work either - the aliens may have thought of that already.  To work, a strategy like this would require a redoubt a *long* way away, not just a few light years.  We're not up to doing anything like this yet.

Comment: Thanks..the idea is that perhaps we should do that as soon as it is possible, not when aliens are already around.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Comment: We might still have a chance: If our generation ship was built long enough before the aliens arrived, but had not reached its target, then it would at the time of the attack be a very, very small point in a very, very large universe. So it might just be overlooked.